# How to delete custom profile in GCP datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I created a new custom profile in datafusion and now I want to delete it. The delete button is disabled and I not able to find other options to delete it. How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

The compute profile must be disabled before it can be deleted.

To disable the profile, go to the *System Admin* page, go to the *Configuration* tab, expand the *System Compute Profiles* section and click on the profile you would like to delete. This will take you to the details page where you can disable the profile (toggle switch in the top right of the page). Now you can click on *Actions* and you should be able to delete the profile.